# CSS Layout: Expanding a page vertically

Tags: css, html

This is the page I am working on right now: http://jsfiddle.net/0xsven/hycRx/

I want the page to expand vertically to fill the whole screen so that the footer is always at the very bottom. I am not searching for a sticky footer! I want the page to expand to the bottom like in this [picture](http://i48.tinypic.com/25q4p79.jpg).

Any idea if this is possible?

---

### Update

I used some confusing words so I am trying to clarify my question:

I want my page to always fill out the viewport vertically, even if there is not enough content. As soon as there is enough content to even extend the viewport the page should be scrollable. In my tests a sticky footer always stays at the bottom of the viewport covering other elements, which I don't want to happen.

One solution I came up with is manipulating/resizing the paddings/margins with jquery so it fits the viewport. But I dislike using javascript for such things.

Comment: ...I'm still fairly sure a sticky footer is what you're after :/ Often pages are designed to look as though the main content element stretches to fill the remainder of the page, but this is usually just an illusion.

Comment: Then show me how to produce that illusion please. I have tried with a stcky footer but it just sticks to the bottom without giving the illusion tha page is that big. Also if the page extends the display then the footer still shows up on the bottom which I don't want.

Comment: Could you perhaps show us a working example of what it is you're trying to achieve? I'm still not certain what your idea of “bottom” is. Bottom of the document? Bottom of the viewport? If it's the bottom of the viewport you mean, then choose Chris Fletcher's answer.

Comment: Well if I had a working example I would not ask here :-) I will update my question to clarify my question.

Comment: After reading your update, I'm certain that a sticky footer is *exactly* what you're after. The conventional sticky footer does not stick to the bottom of the viewport when the content is long enough to fill the viewport. [Did you have a look at how a sticky footer behaves](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)? I'm going to add this comment as an answer, as I'm confident this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with the position attribute, like this:

```
#footer{
    background-color: #222;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: But.. That's a version of the sticky footer.. Exactly what the OP said he didn't want..

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour you're trying to emulate is that of the conventional CSS Sticky Footer.

[Here's a simple example](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="main">
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
#wrap {min-height: 100%; *display:table; *height:100%}
#main {overflow:auto; padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;
} 

/*Opera Fix*/
body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;/
}
```